# How does the temperature of the coil in a simple motor affects its rotational speed?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, temperature, electric-current, electrical-resistance

So I am considering a simple motor made of copper coils, where the coil rotates. Since in general, resistance increases with temperature, I would assume that a higher temperature would result in a higher resistance in the coils themselves. With a constant DC voltage provider, a higher resistance would result in a lower current, decreasing the magnetic force acting on the coil. As a result, the rotational speed of the coil would decrease.

Is this correct? Or are there other factors that come in place?

Answer (score 0):

the first-order effect is just as you describe: when the coils get hot, R goes up, I goes down and if V is constant, the power output of the motor decreases. note that the temperature coefficient of resistivity of the (copper) wire is a relatively small number, so this effect is strongest where the coils in the motor have lots of wire on them and heat transfer out of the coils is poor.

Answer (score 0):

If the magnetic field is produced by a stator coil, and this coil gets hot with increasing resistance, the speed could be even higher, still the power decreases. This field change was/is a standard method to change speed with some kind of simple DC motors. Some motors have the rotor and stator coils in series/parallel mode, in that case a hotter rotor coil could also decrease the static coil's magnetic field resulting in higher speed. Again the power output /momentum is decreasing.
So generally spoken, a hotter motor coil does not always necessarily slow down a motor.